# How do I get information from a database to a session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to start a new PHP session by using information in a database, but I don't know how. Help? Thanks.

For example, I have DatabaseA that has TableB, with RowC. I want to store RowC's firstname into a PHP session. How do I do that?

Comment: I mean this kind of session. $_SESSION['firstname'];

Answer (score 2):

1. get information from the database
2. store it in a session

There are plenty of tutorials on both operations.

Comment: But HOW do you get information from the database? Other than having to type in the rows manually, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: HOW do you get information from the database is a matter of learning PHP basics. Have you any?

Comment: I know how to, but whenever I do it selects either the top or bottom row

Comment: So, if you have a problem with selecting rows, not storing rows in a session, what does session do in your question and why there are no detains provided on the problem you have with selecting rows?

Answer (score 1):

I realize you don't need to parameterize a small controlled query like this, but since you are in the learning phase you should look into PDO and parameterized querys and learn the right way to avoid future headaches.

```
<?php

$host   = "localhost";
$dbname = "mydb";
$user   = "username";
$pass   = "password";

//this is where you set the value you use in your where clause to determine
//what name to get back - I assume you'll use $_GET or $_POST or else to populate this
$name   = "bob";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Problem connecting to DB, try again; if it presists contact admin.";
        exit();
    }

    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sth_select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT row FROM table WHERE firstname = :name");

    $sth_select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sth_select->execute(array('firstname' => $name));

    while ($row = $sth_select->fetch()) {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    }

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
$fn = "";
SELECT RowC FROM TABLE B;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_of_query) {
      $fn = $row['firstname'];
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $fn;
```

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) to understand working with database (MySql) in php.

Comment: Why is $fn blank though?

Comment: This is called initialisation. Its intended value is later set inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT first_name FROM table_name WHERE `field_name` = $value

If you only want the first row:
ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1

The last row:
ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1

Depending on what you WHERE clause has will depend on how many results you get.

If 3 people have the same name and it was WHERE last_name = bob.
3 people with the name Dave Bob will load... if you only want dave...

you need to add

GROUP BY first_name at the end of your query... that will return only one Dave

EDIT you don't need a WHERE's clause i just adding that in for this example. But if you want a specific name (with a single name return) thats the only way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that you are asking for user input in order to limit your query. If you use post to submit the users information, you would do something like this...

```
session_start();

$userdata = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userdata']);
$result = mysql_query("select RowC from TableB where somedata='$userdata'") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$result = $result[0];
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $result;
```

Of course you will have to connect to the database as well, and replace "somedata" with some unique column. Make sure you call `session_start()` as well.

Comment: it will work but such a variable reuse is scaring